# Error making line plot using xts R : cannot mix zero-length and non-zero-length coordinates

Tags: r, xts

I'm attempting to slice two data frames, one representing the date (Date) and one representing a continuous value and graph them using a xts line graph. When I use the full dateframes it works, but when I slice to the last 7 values, it throws the following error. Any thoughts?

Error in segments(xlim[1], y_grid_lines(get_ylim()[[2]]), xlim[2], y_grid_lines(get_ylim()[[2]]),  : 
  cannot mix zero-length and non-zero-length coordinates

```
    library(xts)

Date <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-02-25"), by="days")
Date <- as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

#Date <-tail #Works
Date <-tail(Date,7) #Doesn't Work

T1_EF <- matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=23,sd=3), N, M)
Trial1_EF<- as.matrix(round(Trial1_EF, digits = 6))
T1_EF_counts <- apply(Trial1_EF, 2, function(x) length(na.omit(x)))

#c <-T1_EF_counts #Works
c <-tail(T1_EF_counts,7)#doesn't work


  datN <- data.frame(Date = Date, y = c)



  datN.ts <- xts(datN$y, order.by = datN$Date)
  plot(datN.ts)
  lines(datN.ts, col = 'Green')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this here:
https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/156

xls doesn't like when the y value is a constant.

here is the edited code:

```
library(xts)

Date <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-02-25"), by="days")
Date <- as.POSIXct(Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

#Date <-tail #Works
Date <-tail(Date,7) #Doesn't Work

T1_EF <- matrix( rnorm(N*M,mean=23,sd=3), N, M)
Trial1_EF<- as.matrix(round(Trial1_EF, digits = 6))
T1_EF_counts <- apply(Trial1_EF, 2, function(x) length(na.omit(x)))

#c <-T1_EF_counts #Works
c <-tail(T1_EF_counts,7)#doesn't work


  datN <- data.frame(Date = Date, y = c)



  datN.ts <- xts(datN$y, order.by = datN$Date)
  plot(datN.ts, , ylim=c(300, 600))
  lines(datN.ts, col = 'Green')
```